# Wpf - binding to parent datacontext and specifying context type fails?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

I'm trying to bind to parent data context from DataTemplate. When I do this in this way

```
ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.(viewModels:UmowaViewModel.ZrodlaOprocentowania), 
                                                      RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
```

it fails with "An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in WindowsBase.dll. Additional information: Key cannot be null"

But when I ommit context type it works but I have underscore in VS that property cannot be resolved - why it breaks after specifing data type?

```
ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.(viewModels:UmowaViewModel.ZrodlaOprocentowania), 
                                                      RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
```

Comment: Are those two code excerpts supposed to be the same? Either way, I'm guessing that it doesn't work when you add a type in brackets because that's not a valid `Binding.Path`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure where you got the idea to randomly inject a namespace and `Type` into your `Binding.Path`, but I'm fairly sure that it is invalid... at least, I've never come across any `Binding.Path` like this:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.(viewModels:UmowaViewModel.ZrodlaOprocentowania), 
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
```

Brackets tend to be used in `Binding Path`s to represent Attached Properties, but the `DataContext` property is *not* an Attached Property. Instead of this, you should use a normal `Binding Path` that references just the property name and the `RelativeSource` like this:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext, 
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
```

Now this is clear and correct... we are trying to data bind to the `DataContext` property of the parent `UserControl` object. So to answer your question *why does the second example work but not the first?*, I would say because the second example is valid, but the first is not. You can see the [Property Path Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742451(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN for more help with valid `Binding Path` syntax.

Comment: I'm using this syntaxt since resharper showed me it and it worked in another project.

Comment: It's always best to understand the code that you use *before* you use it. As you can see from the linked page, there is no such syntax described.